# Extract a string from a recurring word to the first white space using R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I'm trying to extract subway stations names from a character vector. Those station names are always preceded with 'METRO-'.

Here's an example.

```
x <- c('BLA BLA BLA METRO-SNOWDON BLA BLI BLU', 'BLA VLA BLU METRO-SQUARE-VICTORIA YES NO')
```

I want to extract the characters following the METRO- until the first white space.

The desired output should look like

```
"METRO-SNOWDON", "METRO-SQUARE-VICTORIA"
```

I can't figure out the "white space" part of the code

```
sub('.*(METRO-)', '\\1', x)
```

Thanks guy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern will work, as long as you never have white space contained within the metro name:

```
gsub(".*?(METRO-.*?)\\s.*", "\\1", x)
```

`.*?` means match anything up until the next part of the pattern matches.

This is particularly important the second time it appears, because we want to end the capturing group at the *first* instance of white space after "METRO". Without the `?`, the the capturing group will include everything up until the final instance of white space.

The above expression returns:

```
[1] "METRO-SNOWDON"         "METRO-SQUARE-VICTORIA"
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation too. I'm getting there (slowly and painfully)

Comment: @ChubSuey this is my favorite Regex resource, it's a nice concise guide with all the key syntax elements: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: @ChubSuey And don't forget to click the green check mark to accept the answer, since it solved your problem.